# unresolved identifier in swift when I use bridging Header

Tags: swift

I want to get devices ip , so I use `ifaddrs.h` example like:

http://footruck.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-get-ip-address-for-ios-devices.html

but not working....

compile error is `use of unresolved identifier "IPChecker"`

In build setting, bridge header already set `{PROJECT}/{PROJECT}-Bridging-Header.h`

and other files just like above link..  please tell me why?

Comment: did you add the "-ObjC" linker-flag in the build settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the header in your bridging header. In `{PROJECT}-Bridging-Header.h` add:

```
#import "IPChecker.h"
```

Some other things to check:

- Did you add `IPChecker.h` and `IPChecker.m` to the Xcode project?
- Do your header search paths in build settings include the location of `IPChecker.h`?
- Try reducing the problem. Does bridging work for other headers? If so, what's the difference?

Comment: In my project, I have main app-container called `main` and other app-extensions called `tunnel`.

when I use IPChecker in `main`. the` tunnel` compile error in build parse .

So I need to do the same thing in `tunnel` like `main`. But I only use IPChecker in `main`, why should I copy same code in tunnel ?

it is another way make it simple, not code duplicates

Comment: @Luke in my case bridging is working for other headers but not the one i want knowing that all settings, configurations, file location is identical. Cleaned the project and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it. But it is still confused me:

In this project, I have main app-container called `main` and other app-extensions called `tunnel`.

when I use `IPChecker` in `main`. the `tunnel` in build parse compile error.

So I need to do the same thing in `tunnel` like `main`.  But I only use `IPChecker` in `main`,  why should I copy same code in `tunnel` ?

it is another way make it simple, not code duplicates